# Matplotlib multiple plots x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having a problem with labelling the X-axis of a multiple plot graph. My current code is as follows:

```
X=range(0, len(departments), 1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(X, department_employees_current, color='b')
ax1.bar(X, department_employees_left, color='r', bottom=department_employees_current)
ax1.set_ylabel('Employees current & left')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(X, department_percentage_attrition, color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('% Attrition')

ax2.set_xticklabels(departments)
```

I am getting all the X-label axis crammed together:
[image]

Comment: I'm very lazy. Could you supply the actual data arrays to make your chart?

Comment: What happens if you set the `xticklabels` on `ax1` instead of `ax2`, i.e. `ax1.set_xticklabels(departments)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to set to position of your x ticks as well as setting the label using:

```
ax2.set_xticks(X)
```

otherwise matplotlib will try and put your labels onto the ticks it generates automatically.

A full example with some fake data:

```
departments = ["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
department_employees_current = [80,800,300]
department_employees_left = [20,100,80]
department_percentage_attrition = [700,50,900]

X=range(0, len(departments), 1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(X, department_employees_current, color='b')
ax1.bar(X, department_employees_left, color='r', bottom=department_employees_current)
ax1.set_ylabel('Employees current & left')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(X, department_percentage_attrition, color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('% Attrition')

ax2.set_xticks(X)
ax2.set_xticklabels(departments)

plt.show()
```

Will give you the required plot:

[image]

Comment: No problem :) If an answer solves your question it is a good idea to upvote and accept in order to mark the question as solved as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers